# ASP.NET MVC is asking me to re-authenticate for PNG files but not GIFs or JPEGs

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, image, iis

For some reason, any time I reference a PNG from my `application.css` file, I get prompted for credentials.  However, I can reference GIFs, JPEGs, etc. from my images directory without a problem.

My routes are set up like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutesTo(RouteCollection routes) {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", "",                   
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}  // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Session", "{action}",
            new { controller = "Session" },
            new { action = "(login|logout|register)" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute("CatchAll",  "{*catchall}",
            new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" });
    }
```

In my CSS, I have this:

```
.iconLocationLarge { background-image: url(../images/icon_vcarea_48x48.png) !important;}
.iconVCLarge { background-image: url(../images/tb-btn-sprite.gif) !important;}
```

The problem is that I get prompted to authenticate again if I use a PNG but not with the GIF.  Why?

Comment: What kind of prompt do you get?  Have you made any auth changes to your web.config?

Comment: I get a 401 and prompted to authenticate over and over again (web app is secured using Integrated authentication ... running on IIS7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved:

The PNG files I was referencing were encrypted.  That is it.

After finally exhausting all other options with IIS and ASP.NET I noticed that each PNG file I was referencing had the attributes "AE" (E= Encrypted).  So the solution was to right-click the folder, click "Advanced" button and de-select the "Encryption" option.

Answer (score 2):

IIS can serve content directly without passing the request to ASP.NET.  I suspect in your case that IIS is set to serve GIF and JPG but not PNG.  See for example http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2006/11/10/Stopping-hot_2D00_linking-with-IIS-and-ASP.NET.aspx for a discussion on the topic.  See also http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/4c840252-fab7-427e-a197-7facb6649106.mspx?mfr=true.

Assuming this is IIS6, open the IIS Manager from Administrative Tools, right click on the local computer node, click on MIME types, check that PNG is registered as "image/png".  You can also configure this at the individual web site level.

Make sure there is no other filter that could cause the issue, e.g. the UrlScan ISAPI filter.

Comment: This appears to be the case.  Question is ... what do I need to include in setup so that PNG is process like GIF and JPG?  As far as I can tell, there is nothing specific for gifs/jpegs and so I'd assume that png would be processed the same way.

Comment: You need to check your IIS configuration, see updated answer.

Comment: Yes ... PNG is registered and mapped to image/png.  And I don't see any filters per se that would cause the issue.

Comment: See the solution below.  This was happening because the PNG files I was hitting had the encryption bit set.  Thanks for your comments though as I'm sure they will be of value to someone perusing this thread at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but probably you should add ignore routes for all static content regardless.

[ASP.NET MVC thinks my virtual directory is a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730335/asp-net-mvc-thinks-my-virtual-directory-is-a-controller/2730472#2730472)

Comment: This did not work.  ASP.NET still attempting to process .png files rather than serving them up like any other image (e.g. .gif, .jpeg)