# Getting an error serving images from App_Themes when using precompilation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, app-themes

I have an ASP.NET site with both WebForms and MVC sections to it.  When I try to precompile the site, everything works except serving images/css from under App_Themes.

If I request something like `/foo/App_Themes/themeName/my.png`, I get this error:

```
The file '/foo/App_Themes/themeName/my.png.cshtml' is in the special directory 'App_Themes', which is not allowed.
```

I only get this when precompiling, it works fine otherwise.  Presumably MVC routing is interfering somehow, but I don't know why or how to disable it.

In case it's helpful, here's the stack trace:

```
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ValidateVirtualPathInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean codeFile) +9930801
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +455
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +103
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +165
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(String virtualPath, Boolean throwIfNotFound) +33
System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper.GetObjectFactory(String virtualPath) +26
System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper.ExistsInPrecompiledSite(String virtualPath) +80
System.Web.WebPages.BuildManagerWrapper.Exists(String virtualPath) +13
System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Exists>b__0(IVirtualPathFactory factory) +15
System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +146
System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryManager.Exists(String virtualPath) +73
System.Web.WebPages.DefaultDisplayMode.GetDisplayInfo(HttpContextBase httpContext, String vir tualPath, Func`2 virtualPathExists) +42
System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetDisplayInfoForVirtualPath>b__8(IDisplayMode mode) +22
System.Linq.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() +104
System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +94
System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider.GetDisplayInfoForVirtualPath(String virtualPath, HttpContextBase httpContext, Func`2 virtualPathExists, IDisplayMode currentDisplayMode, Boolean requireConsistentDisplayMode) +204
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.GetRouteLevelMatch(String pathValue, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions, IVirtualPathFactory virtualPathFactory, HttpContextBase context, DisplayModeProvider displayModeProvider) +201
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.MatchRequest(String pathValue, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions, IVirtualPathFactory virtualPathFactory, HttpContextBase context, DisplayModeProvider displayModes) +281
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRoute.DoPostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +235
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +89
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Comment: It's not MVC routing as much as any of the `App_XXX` folders are considered special folders in IIS.  Given that the role of the `App_Themes` folder was to allow you to provide css/images/skin files for WebForms controls and the role of this folder is "depreciated (lack of a better word) in MVC, I would assume the razor view engine is set to toss an error when it is validating the paths to your content files.  Any of the searches I have done mention that this folder is no longer relevant in an MVC site and even a few mentioning having to include `<head runat="server">` in earlier MVC versions.

Comment: The above assumption on the exception is based on the first line in the stack trace.  Here is an example of having to change the pipeline in an applcation with same error: http://forums.smartertools.com/threads/the-special-directory-app_themes.15865/

Comment: @Tommy: I suppose that is why nobody else on the internet seems to have ever lived in my hell-for-today.  I think I have a patch though, by IgnoreRoute'ing App_Themes, which I'll post as an answer if it  continues to test successfully.

Comment: Agreed, there was little no info out there regarding MVC and the App_Themes folder, good luck to you on getting it working!

Comment: Sigh... `routes.IgnoreRoute("App_Themes/{*anything}");` fixed it locally under Cassini but did not have any affect when deployed under IIS6.  Inexplicable.

Comment: This worked in Win2008/IIS7: 
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*appthemes}", new { appthemes = @"App_Themes(/.*)?" });

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same problem and could only fix it by changing the "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" attribute of the "modules" node in the web.config to false, however I am looking for a solution that lets me keep this as true

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue but it only occured when I published my web application and would work fine locally. I came up with two potential solutions.

**Hacky solution**

By looking at the source code I could see it was throwing this error as the "BuildManager" object had a field "_forbiddenTopLevelDirectories" which it would check and throw an expection if the path was in a number of special directories, "App_Themes" being one of them.

So by using reflection I remove the "App_Themes" object from the collection by calling the following code in the global file `Application_Start` method.

```
        var buildManagerType = typeof(BuildManager);
        var theBuilderManager = buildManagerType.GetField("_theBuildManager"
             , BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
             .GetValue(null);

        var forbiddenDirectoryField = buildManagerType
        .GetField("_forbiddenTopLevelDirectories",
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
       .GetValue(theBuilderManager);

        var removeMethod = forbiddenDirectoryField.GetType().GetMethod("Remove");

        removeMethod.Invoke(forbiddenDirectoryField, new object[] { "App_Themes" });
```

This solved the issue and my css + image files would now be correctly served when deployed. **Warning** - I do not have a good understanding of the consequences of editing the `_forbiddenTopLevelDirectories` field and doing this may have unintended side effects.

**Alternative solution**

Another thing i noticed was I would not recieve the errors when the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests attribute of the modules node in the webconfig was set to false. So if your application can work with this set to false consider this solution

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">`